# Sed command inside a for loop with variables

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed

I have a file named dates.txt which contains the following:

```
DATE_1
DATE_2
DATE_3
DATE_4
DATE_5
DATE_6
DATE_7
```

I just want to replace DATE_i with some dates that are stored in v array using sed command.
To do that I tried a for loop and a sed command (file test.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
v[1]=`date -d "7 days ago" '+%d\/%m\/%y'`
v[2]=`date -d "6 days ago" '+%d\/%m\/%y'`
v[3]=`date -d "5 days ago" '+%d\/%m\/%y'`
v[4]=`date -d "4 days ago" '+%d\/%m\/%y'`
v[5]=`date -d "3 days ago" '+%d\/%m\/%y'`
v[6]=`date -d "2 days ago" '+%d\/%m\/%y'`
v[7]=`date -d "1 days ago" '+%d\/%m\/%y'`

cat dates.txt|for j in {1..7};do sed "s/DATE_$j/${v[$j]}/";done
```

The problem is that this command replaces only the first date. If you run test.sh:

```
$ ./test.sh 
14/03/16
DATE_2
DATE_3
DATE_4
DATE_5
DATE_6
DATE_7
```

The output I am expecting is:

```
14/03/16
15/03/16
16/03/16
17/03/16
18/03/16
19/03/16
20/03/16
```

I cannot understand why this is not working.
Could anyone please explain why this is happening and propose a proper solution for this problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:** What's happening is that the first iteration of the `for` loop is consuming all of the lines you're piping to its standard input. First of all, let's modify `test.sh` to contain an `echo` statement in the last line so that we can see what's happening:

```
cat dates.txt|for j in {1..7};do echo $j; sed "s/DATE_$j/${v[$j]}/";done
```

You'll see the output from `test.sh` is the following:

```
1
13/03/16
DATE_2
DATE_3
DATE_4
DATE_5
DATE_6
DATE_7
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Next, modify `dates.txt` to read:

```
DATE_1
DATE_2
DATE_1
DATE_4
DATE_1
DATE_6
DATE_1
```

, where we've turned every other line into `DATE_1` for demonstration purposes. Now, the output reads:

```
1
13/03/16
DATE_2
13/03/16
DATE_4
13/03/16
DATE_6
13/03/16
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

So you see that the first iteration of the `for` loop (when `$j == 1`) is processing every line that `cat` is passing to the `for` loop. After that,  the subsequent iterations of the `for` loop (`$j == 2..7`) still run, but they don't receive any input stream (so, in the above example, they just `echo` the current value of `$j` and don't pass any input to `sed`). That's why you were observing that it was changing only the first line.

**Solution:** Modify the last line to read:

```
for j in {1..7}; do head -$j dates.txt | tail -1 | sed "s/DATE_$j/${v[$j]}/"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat dates.txt | sed 's/^DATE_//g'
```

This will strip `DATE_` at the beginning of a line (`^`), leaving the number (or anything else on the line).  No need for a loop at all!

Comment: Yes ok!! My fault for bad description! Actually I don't want to replace with 1,2,3 etc.. I want to replace with real dates. This was just a test I was made.
So you are actually right about this, but if we want to replace with another word, lets say datetime_1, datetime_2 etc..
Sorry for the bad example
Thanks

Comment: @argi You should update the question accordingl to show exactly what your input and expected output looks like. As it stands, it's simplified so much that any solution other than this one here doesn't make much sense.